# CSS Centering with Transform

Tags: css, centering

why does centering with transform translate and left 50% center perfectly (with position relative parent) but not right 50%?

Working example:

```
span[class^="icon"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

Example that doesn't center:

```
span[class^="icon"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Because `translateX(-50%)` moves something back to the *left* 50% (because of the `-` negative value), which means it pairs with `left: 50%;` to center something.

If you want to use `right: 50%;` then use that with `translateX(50%)` to center.

```css
* {margin:0;}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%,-50%);
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

body:after, body:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}

body:after {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  height: 1px;
}
body:before {
  left: 50%;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<span>center me</span>
```

Comment: also depends on `direction` rtl or ltr

Comment: @Banzay feel free to leave your own answer clarifying the role of `direction` on this type of positioning. When using `left` or `right` it shouldn't matter what the `direction` of the document is, since you're specifying `right` or `left` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWdrBG

Comment: that was more question, than a note. thanx :)

Comment: I'm more curious on how to make the cool red target line to show the center... still wrap my head around `body:after` `body:before`. Anyone could shed a light? (On some tries I feel like css of :after or :before can be swapped), doesn't matter which one stays before or after

Comment: @aanhlle, `::before` and `::after` are pseudo elements - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements. They're somewhat interchangeable, but it's worth noting that `::after` will stack with a higher `z-index` than `::before` by default since `::after` comes "after" `::before` :)

Answer (score 8):

From what I understand, `top:` and `left:` really mean "how far the object's top edge is from the top of its container" (container refers to the closest parent element with a relative position) and "how far the object's left edge is from the left of its container". Specifically, `top: 50%` means that the object is shifted by 50% of the container's height, and `left: 50%` means the object is shifted 50% of the container's width.

Once the origin of the element is at the center, you can see that by shifting the element to the left by half of its width and up by half of its height, the center of the object will be at the origin rather than its upper left corner.

If we did `right: 50%` instead, then the right side of the element would be shifted from the right side of the container by 50% of the container's width, meaning that its [upper-right edge](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_right.asp) is on the origin. Therefore, by shifting it to the right by 50% of its width and up by 50% of its height (`transform(50%, -50%)`), we will center the object.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. I found it more intuitive.