# overflow: hidden from the middle

Tags: html, css

```css
#main {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main div {
  display: inline-block;
  heighh: 200px;
  width: 1000px;
  border: solid black;
}
```

```html
        <div id="main">
          <div id="first">
            1
          </div>
          <div id="second">
            2
          </div id="third">
          <div>
            3
          </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to do something in my css code.
The code has 3 div objects, and the width of each one of them is 1000px.
I want those 3 divs to be in the same line, so i wrote that to the father div:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

In each one of them I entered:

```
display: inline-block;
```

The thing is they all cut to the right, but I want them to be cut from both right and left equally.
That means that if there is 10px overflow area, i want 5px to be cut to the right and 5px to the left.
How can I do that?

Many thanks,

Image of what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with cut?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/KV5wjwV.png
the first one is the way it is looking right now
the second is the desired result

Comment: Add the complete code here. cannot see any output with the stuff you have added.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: #main {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main div {
  display: inline-block;
  heighh: 200px;
  width: 1000px;
  border: solid black;
}

      <div id="main">
          <div id="first">
            1
          </div>
          <div id="second">
            2
          </div id="third">
          <div>
            3
          </div>
        </div>

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use flexbox to achieve the effect you're looking for, though it's not particularly clean, and a bit advanced for a beginner.

Instead of putting all the children inside your `#main`, we put them in another container right inside `#main` that we'll call `#wrapper`. We use flexbox to put all its children (`#first`, `#second`, `#third`) on the same line, and we make this container arbitrarily wide (in this example, `9999px`) so that all of the items will fit on the same line no matter what.

Then, we use `position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to center that container within `#main`. Applying `overflow: hidden` to `#main` as you already had gets you the cut-off effect you're looking for.

For more information about these techniques, check out [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [This question about centering with `transform` and absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121150/css-centering-with-transform).

```css
#main {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 9999px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first">
      1
    </div>
    <div id="second">
      2
    </div>
    <div id="third">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

on your case you have 3 div tags with a fixed width ,so it can be easily achieved by setting `margin-left` of it's parent .set `margin-left:calc(50%-1500px);` to your parent element it will work fine,
>

- 50% is half the width of the screen.
- here 1500px is 1.5 times of width of your child elements(1000px).

here I added an example to demonstrate with child width:300px;

```css
#main {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left:calc(50% - 450px);
}

#main div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
          <div id="first">
            1
          </div>
          <div id="second">
            2
          </div >
          <div id="third">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This isn't a perfect solution, because it doesn't account for border width or the width of the space between elements that you get from `display: inline-block`, though it's probably close enough for the asker's uses.

Comment: @Geo1088 border width is not a matter here because I'm added box-sizing : border-box; and the space between the blocks can be easily managed by adjusting the margin left value,I give him the basic  logic.

Comment: @Geo1088 assume if the margin between div tags are 10px then equation just change to margin-left:calc(50%-(1500px+20px));

Comment: Didn't notice the `box-sizing`, good call. However, there is a space between them that's always there even if you set `margin: 0` because of the way HTML whitespace is handled with `display: inline-block`. There is an actual text node between each element, containing nothing but a space, unless you have no whitespace between the child tags in HTML. This is why I almost always use flexbox for this type of thing - it ignores whitespace in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution without extra element is to simply make the container a flexbox one and center the elements:

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /*center to have overflow from both side*/
  overflow:hidden; /*hide the overflow*/
}

#main div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: solid black;
  flex-shrink:0; /* Don't shrink element so they overflow */
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="first">
    1
  </div>
  <div id="second">
    2
  </div>
  <div id="third">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is some related question to better understand what is happening:

[Why is a flex-child limited to parent size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492208/8620333)

[Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/8620333)