# how to emulate responsive cover behavior for a full-screen image while positioning smaller images on it?

Tags: css

I try to make an image fill the whole screen, the same way it will if I put a `background-image` to the body with the `background-size` set to `cover`. But I also need to place small images on this image, to create animations, like an animal showing in a tree for instance.

In order to do that, I need to place these small images in percentages position and size of the image, so I cannot use a `background-image`.

What I do then, is to put the background image in a container, place the other images as absolute in the container, and make the container the size of the first image. Then I try to simulate the `cover` behavior with `min-width` and `min-height`, but it doesn't exactly do the same : the image don't scale down as much as the screen scale down (on firefox at least).

**example of real cover effect :**

*(click on "full page" and use "developer tools" > "responsive design mode" to play with the size of the screen)*

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683009427619-a1a11b799e05?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

**example of simulated cover effect :**

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
}
#img_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}
#bg_img {
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#cat {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_wrapper">
  <img id="bg_img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683009427619-a1a11b799e05?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D">
  <img id="cat" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/01/00/15/png-2702691_960_720.png">
</div>
```

as you can see (on firefox at least), the cat keeps the right place and size, and the image will always at least cover the screen, but the image does not take the smaller covering size, so for example the guy in the bottom middle of the image quickly disappear on a mobile size screen with the second solution, when it does not with the background cover solution

Do you know how to fix that ? or a better way to do the intending behavior (the capability to place small images on a big one for any screen size) ?

## EDIT

### CBroe's answer works, So I'll show a complete example of it here.

I replaced its centering solution with one using flexbox, but it has no impact on the result.

The main idea is to use a container that has a fix ratio, so you can use a background image on it and it will not "move" relatively to the container's borders. This fixed ratio is a square.

Then you need to make this container always covering the screen size, and we do that with vmax unit (clever)

**The result :**

```css
body {
  height:100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* flex centering method : */
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
}
#img_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1683009427619-a1a11b799e05?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  /* to get the square around the screen : */
  /* (change to vmin to get it inside the screen) */
  width: 100vmax;
  height: 100vmax;
  /* to avoid flex centering to shrink the width : */
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
#cat {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div id="img_wrapper">
  <img id="cat" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/01/00/15/png-2702691_960_720.png">
</div>
```

Comment: The proper "equivalent" for`background-size: cover` would be [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

Comment: @CBroe I tried that, but I don't see how it can let me place the small images on top of the background one ? For what I saw it reproduce the problem that I loose the dimension of the big image. Instead I need some kind of container with the same dimensions of this image, in order to place the small images in percentage. Or did I miss something ?

Comment: Your question sounded like that was your main issue, replacing the background image with an actual one. If you need the position of other elements to stay "consistent" in relation, regardless of whether cutting off parts of the image happens on the left/right, or top/bottom, then you will indeed have to put the whole thing into a container, that keeps its aspect ratio the same in all situations. And then you need to position that container accordingly, within the viewport.

Comment: @CBroe two points : it's not easy for me to find the correct English sentence to describe my problem, so if you think of a better formulation to present my question, I'll be glad to edit it :) Secondly, for what I understand, what you describe is what i showed on my snippet, but it doesn't solve the problem of the "minimal covering size". Or are you describing another way of doing it ?

Comment: I still can't tell how _exactly_ you want this to behave. You explicitly mentioned the guy at the bottom - is he supposed to be visible at all times (then you would have to position your scaled image a `bottom center`), or is he allowed to "disappear", when the viewport dimensions "require" that? And whee the cat is actually _supposed_ to go - hard to tell, on _that_ background image. You could have provided a background image instead, where you mark that spot with a red "X" or something, and the whole thing would be much clearer.

Comment: But since you'll need to work with an "oversized" container here anyway, you can still use background image, there should be no need to switch to an "actual" image.  I would start by giving the container `100vmin` for width _and_ height - that gets you a square, that fits _into_ your viewport. [...]

Comment: [...] You can now easily position your other elements on there, using percentages. Once you arranged everything to your satisfaction, you switch from `100vmin`, to `100vmax` - now you have a square, that fully covers the smaller viewport dimension, and overflows it in the other. Now all that's left is to properly position it within the viewport.

Comment: my example here is not the real situation, those are free images found on the internet. I don't care where should the cat go, what I care is that once it is positioned and sized, it doesn't move or scale when the screen size change. About the guy in the bottom, I just mentioned it to show the difference of behavior with the first example which is a basic background-size:cover; example. You can see that my "imitation" of the covering effect is not acting the same. I provided both example to allow you to compare. to see it, you need to dynamically change screen size as i mentioned.

Comment: @CBroe the use of vmax is clever, I didn't know this unit ! it's almost working, I still cant figure how to place the div in the center without losing the placement of the small images, but I'll play with this solution until I figure it out. Hopefully this is the right solution :)

Comment: As long as the wrapper itself is "positioned" (i.e., has a `position` value other than the default `static`), it serves as the reference point for its absolute positioned children. So if you got those set up in their correct positions using percentages, you should then be able to center the container in the viewport using something like the "classic" approach of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121193/1427878, `position: absolute; top: 50%; right: 50%; transform: translate(50%,-50%);` And to not get scrollbars, you'll want to set `overflow:hidden` for `html`/`body` then.

Comment: yes, I was trying to do it with flexbox, adding place-content:center; and place-items:center; to the body, but I didn't understand why it transformed the width of the div that need to stay a square. Then i found the problem : I need to tell it to not shrink with flex-shrink:0; Of course your solution with transform works also well

Comment: Also, to keep images scaling along together, it would work easier if both of them have the same size to keep offset values matching the same area :) different size and ratio makes it difficult

Comment: @CBroe thx, i would never have think of this vmax unit by myself, if you want to post your solution i can make it the accepted answer

Comment: @G-Cyrillus you're right ,but in my case it wont work because actually I animate the images and make them move :) anyway the solution of CBroe works well

Comment: great, it's been sorted out :)

Comment: yes thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you'll need to work with an "oversized" container here anyway, you can still use background image, there should be no need to switch to an "actual" image. I would start by giving the container 100vmin for width and height - that gets you a square, that fits *into* your viewport.

You can now easily position your other elements on there, using percentages. Once you arranged everything to your satisfaction, you switch from 100vmin, to 100vmax - now you have a square, that fully covers the smaller viewport dimension, and overflows it in the other. Now all that's left is to properly position it within the viewport.

As long as the wrapper itself is "positioned" (i.e., has a position value other than the default static), it serves as the reference point for its absolute positioned children. So if you got those set up in their correct positions using percentages, you should then be able to center the container in the viewport using something like the "classic" approach of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121193/1427878:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 50%;
transform: translate(50%,-50%);
```

And to not get scrollbars, you'll want to set `overflow:hidden`for whatever element that container is in - could be html/body, if this is supposed to be the only element, or an additional container that has `height: 100vh` set, or something like that.